Snowflake Snowsight: internal Stage not showing files (for download)
wanted to download files from an internal stage. Unloaded them from a view there. There should be also files uploaded. My user in its current role is the owner of the stage. With list I see there are files existing and also the GUI says (4 Files) as shown in the following screenshot. But I can't select download as referred to in the help under "Managing staged files": https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-stage-ui#:~:text=Managing%20staged%20files,remove%20the%20file%20from%20the%20stage.

Any idea what prevents the files to be shown? Maybe because the encryption is set to Client-side? Directory table is also enabled.
Granted also ALL (privileges) to the role on the schema. As I was able to see the Files normally when the ACCOUNTADMIN role (owner of the schema) was owner of that internal stage.

Thanks for the help!

In the first screenshot you show, you should be able to see the four files (maybe hit the refresh icon if you can't). Against each file there is an "..." icon - click on that and there is an option to download the file. It works fine for me


I know that it should look like this. It simply doesn't. I was able to see the files when transfering Stage Ownership to the Accountadmin who is also owner of the Schema and DB. I also already granted All (privileges) to the Schema to the used Role and it wasn't resolved. The (4 Files) I only get after the first refresh on the first load it always says no files at all.

So does the role you are using have USAGE on the stage?

It's the owner so yeah should have. But it also said: Cannot grant or revoke USAGE on an internal staging location; use READ and/or WRITE instead. So I granted Read and Write addtionally just to make sure but same outcome.

Added the privileges on the schema to the question.
